# Add new row with button jquery then remove the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a table that have "`add`" button to add new rows in every new row then remove the previous button. I have a code like this.

```js
 $("#insert-more").click(function () {
        $("#mytable").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
       <thead>
         <th>Check</th>
         <th>Nama Klien</th>
         <th>Nama File</th>
         <th>Ukuran</th>
         <th>Bahan</th>
         <th>Jumlah</th>
         <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" value="" data-toggle="checkbox">
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
           <select class="form-control">
             <option value="default">KLIEN :</option>
             <option value="default">ELV</option>
             <option value="default">ZYTA</option>
             <option value="default">LOUSALUNA</option>
             <option value="default">MYLADY</option>
            </select>
           </td>
           <td>
            <select class="form-control">
             <option value="default">FILES :</option>
             <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
             <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
             <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
             <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
             <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
            </select>
           </td>
           <td>
            <select class="form-control">
             <option value="default">UKURAN :</option>
             <option value="default">110</option>
             <option value="default">115</option>
             <option value="default">120</option>
             <option value="default">130</option>
             <option value="default">150</option>
            </select>
           </td>
           <td>
            <select class="form-control">
             <option value="default">BAHAN :</option>
             <option value="default">MAXMARA</option>
             <option value="default">VOAL INDO</option>
             <option value="default">VOAL INDIA</option>
             <option value="default">DIAMOND</option>
             <option value="default">SILKY</option>
            </select>
           </td>
           <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="" value=""></td>
           <td><button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">ADD</button></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
```

Or you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/f6xcqy2s/.
In that code the add button will show up in every rows, but i wanted the add button just show up in new row only, so there will be one button only. Do you know the way?

Comment: your code work fine, just put button outside of the table like this:-https://jsfiddle.net/4zvykjex/

Comment: No, i want it to be inline with the new row

Answer (score 3):

Hide the button like below.change the id of the button to a class and bind the button like below.it works perfectly

```
$('body').on('click','.insert-more',function(){
    $("#mytable").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
    $(this).hide();
})
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6xcqy2s/3/) is the fiddle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to put add button outside the #mytable (table) so you can get your desire output only change html part as i pasted here.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>Check</th>
                                        <th>Nama Klien</th>
                                        <th>Nama File</th>
                                        <th>Ukuran</th>
                                        <th>Bahan</th>
                                        <th>Jumlah</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="" data-toggle="checkbox">
                                            </label>
                                          </td>
                                            <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">KLIEN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">ELV</option>
                                              <option value="default">ZYTA</option>
                                              <option value="default">LOUSALUNA</option>
                                              <option value="default">MYLADY</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">FILES :</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">UKURAN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">110</option>
                                              <option value="default">115</option>
                                              <option value="default">120</option>
                                              <option value="default">130</option>
                                              <option value="default">150</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">BAHAN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">MAXMARA</option>
                                              <option value="default">VOAL INDO</option>
                                              <option value="default">VOAL INDIA</option>
                                              <option value="default">DIAMOND</option>
                                              <option value="default">SILKY</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                            <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="" value=""></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </table>
                                <tr>
                                <td><button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">ADD</button></td></tr></table>
```

let me know is it ok for you ?

Comment: So the button will be outside the table? no, i want the button is inline with the new row

Answer (score 0):

Here first we create an event handler function and assign it to `clickHandler`. Then when we append the button into the table row after that we assign that click handler to the newly added button using the code as`$("#insert-more").click(clickHandler);`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
 var clickHandler = function() {
    
    $("#mytable").each(function () {
     
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {          
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            
        } else {
           
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
    $(this).remove();
    $("#insert-more").click(clickHandler);
};
$("#insert-more").click(clickHandler);

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>Check</th>
                                     <th>Nama Klien</th>
                                     <th>Nama File</th>
                                     <th>Ukuran</th>
                                     <th>Bahan</th>
                                     <th>Jumlah</th>
                                     <th></th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                         <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="" data-toggle="checkbox">
                                            </label>
                                          </td>
                                         <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">KLIEN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">ELV</option>
                                              <option value="default">ZYTA</option>
                                              <option value="default">LOUSALUNA</option>
                                              <option value="default">MYLADY</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">FILES :</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                              <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">UKURAN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">110</option>
                                              <option value="default">115</option>
                                              <option value="default">120</option>
                                              <option value="default">130</option>
                                              <option value="default">150</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <select class="form-control">
                                              <option value="default">BAHAN :</option>
                                              <option value="default">MAXMARA</option>
                                              <option value="default">VOAL INDO</option>
                                              <option value="default">VOAL INDIA</option>
                                              <option value="default">DIAMOND</option>
                                              <option value="default">SILKY</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </td>
                                         <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="" value=""></td>
                                         <td><button id="insert-more" class="insert-more btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">ADD</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Is it work fine for you? Is this is the expected output that you want?

Comment: It is, but i've got better solution with less code. but yeah thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/f6xcqy2s/4/

```js
$(document).on('click', "#insert-more", function () {
    $('#mytable tbody')
     .append(`<tr>${$(this).closest('tr').html()}</tr>`);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Nama Klien</th>
    <th>Nama File</th>
    <th>Ukuran</th>
    <th>Bahan</th>
    <th>Jumlah</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="" data-toggle="checkbox">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="default">KLIEN :</option>
          <option value="default">ELV</option>
          <option value="default">ZYTA</option>
          <option value="default">LOUSALUNA</option>
          <option value="default">MYLADY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="default">FILES :</option>
          <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
          <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
          <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
          <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
          <option value="default">TWOTONE 1</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="default">UKURAN :</option>
          <option value="default">110</option>
          <option value="default">115</option>
          <option value="default">120</option>
          <option value="default">130</option>
          <option value="default">150</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="default">BAHAN :</option>
          <option value="default">MAXMARA</option>
          <option value="default">VOAL INDO</option>
          <option value="default">VOAL INDIA</option>
          <option value="default">DIAMOND</option>
          <option value="default">SILKY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="" value=""></td>
      <td><button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">ADD</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the solution, amount of `jQuery` code is very less.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah that's very good. But what's the difference beetwen hide(); and remove(); i mean i know hide(); is hide remove(); is remove but there must be a difference right?

Comment: @naovalluthfi. Yes there is a different. `Hide` will set `display:none` property, whereas `remove` will remove the element from the `DOM`.  If you want to hide then please use hide instead of remove.

Comment: so which is better?

Comment: @naovalluthfi If you don't want to use the element in future then it's better to `remove`.